# Can Resharper move any code blocks to another #region?

Tags: c#, region, resharper-8.0

I used *CodeRush* @DevExpress. It have member icons and you can easily code blocks move to any `#region`. But I didn't do that in *ReSharper*. I hope find a solution.

Coderush doing it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ReSharper you can use the **File Structure** window. You can move an element by dragging it to a now position in the list of elements.

[image: ReSharper File Structure window]

In the example above I just added some regions to demonstrate how the File Structure window supports regions. Personally I try to avoid regions and see them as a sign of a class that has grown too big and needs refactoring. Furtunately, I can just click the small x in the corner to delete region without removing what is inside the region.